# File System API - Adding text instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, browser, native-file-system-api-js

Say I have a text file with the following content:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

And I want to use the File System API to insert a new row in this file, in order to get the following:

```
AAA
XXX
BBB
CCC
```

For that I have the following code:

```js
const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker()

const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable({ keepExistingData: true })
await writable.write({
  type: "write",
  position: 4,
  data: "XXX",
})
await writable.close()
```

However the result is the following:

```
AAA
XXX
CCC
```

Is there a way to achieve this without loading the whole content of the file in memory and then overwriting?

Comment: No, since you are inserting content